# Fetching a data from a service and display it in the component when it loads/renders : Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a data in my service 'MySharedService' that has a value in 'MyOutputTemp'. I want to show it in a component when the component loads.

Here is my component:

```
@Component({

    template: `....
                <p>{{MyOutputHere}}
                .....`

    providers: [MySharedService]

})

export class MyOutputComponent implements OnInit{

    MyOutputHere: string;

    constructor (private _mySharedService: MySharedService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        console.log('Getting value from the service: ' + this._mySharedService.MyOutputTemp); //says undefined
        this.MyOutputHere = this._mySharedService.MyOutputTemp;
        console.log('Value in the component: ' +this.MyOutputHere);//says undefined

    }
}
```

Here is my service:

```
@Injectable()
    export class MySharedService{

        MyOutputTemp: string;

        assignOutput(incomingParameter: string){

            this.MyOutputTemp = incomingParameter;
            console.log('Assigned value: ' + this.MyOutputTemp);
            //the value is successfully assigned and I can get a print 

        } //I am calling it in another component. It is successfully assigning the value. Consider MyOutputTemp has value now.

    }
```

What I tried: using ngOnInit() to get the value from the service, and put it in the 'MyOutputHere'.
What happens: {{MyOutputHere}} shows no value. If I print the value in the console it says "undefined".

What It conceptually wrong here?
And, How can I get the value of MyOutputTemp from the service and show it in the component?

Comment: you haven't called `assignOutput` which assigns some value to `MyOutputTemp`. You should call the function first to set it.

Comment: I am calling it in another component. It is successfully assigning the value. Consider MyOutputTemp has value.

Comment: did  you debug to see if the value is set when `ngOnInit` event fires within your component?

Comment: Yes I did. I tried printing the value in the console. It says undefined.

Comment: `ngOnInit` event is executed when your component has started initializing, and for some reason the call to set value to `MyOutputTemp` is not completed. I would suggest you call the function instead and try setting the value.

Comment: The call is completed. MyOutputTemp has the value. I can print it in the console. But, when I am trying to get the value in ngOnInit it says undefined. For some reason ngOnInit is not getting the value. I am wondering, why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132071/discussion-between-tanvir-hk-shuvo-and-amit-kumar-ghosh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the `MyOutputTemp` variable in the service a `static` variable.

for example:

```
@Injectable()
export class MySharedService{

    static MyOutputTemp: string;

    assignOutput(incomingParameter: string){

        MySharedService.MyOutputTemp = incomingParameter;

    }
}
```

in the component:

```
export class MyOutputComponent implements OnInit{

    MyOutputHere: string;

    constructor (private _mySharedService: MySharedService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        console.log('Getting value from the service: ' + MySharedService.MyOutputTemp);
        this.MyOutputHere = MySharedService.MyOutputTemp;
        console.log('Value in the component: ' +this.MyOutputHere);
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that for every component, a new instance of the service is injected. Making the varible static ensures it is the same across all instances.

Cheers!